# Visual Studio 2013 как создать проект на С?

Tags: c, ide

Возможно ли это? Если нет, то какую ИДЕ для Си использовать? Что-нибудь общепризнанное типа Идеи для Javac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

создаете c++ проэкт и пишите в нем код на **С**

Answer (score 2):

Не пробовал в 2013, но в более ранних версиях создавался обычный проект. А вместо *.cpp файлов нужно было создавать* .c файлы.